# Angular 1.x and IE causes infinite digest cycles on window.open

Tags: javascript, angularjs

window.open on a non angular URL works fine but when used with an angular url it causes infinite digest cycle. This is happening only in IE.

```
Sample code
$window.open("www.google.com") -- works
$window.open("#/search") -- causes infinite cycle
```

Angular version - 1.2.14
IE 11

Comment: Is there any redirection on your state handler? Does this happen an all browsers? Can you foresee a example Codepen / JSFiddle?

Comment: Thanks for checking, but it seems like a known bug 
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/15556
Since I cannot upgrade my angular version I am trying a dirty fix, if the url starts with '/#/' then use location.url or else window.open :(